# Different colors on gridView items retrieved from Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm pretty new to this and I'm a bit stumped. Trying to have various background colours on gridView items but all the ways I know of don't seem to work, because the data is coming from firebase.

```
    var colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.yellow,
  ];

  Widget gridPost(
    String Name,
    String JobTitle,
    String Company,
    String photo,
  ) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        color: colors[index]
      )),}
```

This doesn't work because of the 'index' part of colors[index]. if I add int index to the gridPost widget, it then wants it also as

```
  return gridPost(
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['index'],)
```

but that doesn't work either because that doesn't exist in Firebase. adding a dummy field to firebase also didn't work. Please help :)

This is more or less what I'm after

[image: This is more less what I'm after]

Comment: what will be the logic for gridColor? it can come from database or you need to fixed some logic or just random color

Comment: can you share the data you are getting and UI screenshot you want to achieve?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I'd like it to be from a list of colors I specify

Comment: But it is possible you will get more items from database than `colors` contains. the image seems random color/generate from image major color

Comment: @MunsifAli I've added the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create random color and use it in the background you can do it like this

```
 Widget gridPost(
String Name,
String JobTitle,
String Company,
String photo,
) {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
    color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)
  )),}
```

**EDIT**
if you want to select from the list try this code:

```
Widget gridPost(
String Name,
String JobTitle,
String Company,
String photo,
 ) {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
    color: colors[math.Random().nextInt(colors.length)]
  )),}
```

Comment: Sorry no, I'm looking to do it from a list of colours not to make a random colour

Comment: what if your items increased from the colors list length?

Comment: can the colors in the list be reused? that would be ideal.

Comment: check the answer now i updated it and now random color will be selected from the colors list

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a method like this :

```dart
List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.yellow,
  ];



Widget gridPost(
    //add other properties that you need
     int index,
    ) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        color: colors[index]
      )),}
```

call method like this :

```dart
return gridPost(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['index'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when I try it like this I get the following: "Can't have modifier 'required' here. Try removing 'required'.", and "The named parameter 'index' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'index'."

Comment: @OlaMichalska, I get to know the problem, I edited my answer please try that way.